# Regex to find and replace string with starting and ending text in PHP

Tags: php

i want a php function probably regular expression to find and replace a string that starts with a constant string and ends up with a specific string and the text mentioned within those strings.. e.g.,

`[Starting String]..anything.. [Ending String]`

and i want to remove above pattern of string with empty space.. Kindly advise!!

Comment: Give an example, please.

Comment: Please, explain better what do you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('[Starting String]') . 
                          '.*?' .
                          preg_quote('[Ending String]') . '/', '', $str);
```

`preg_quote` is used to be sure that you will not break the regexp with some specific for regexp characters in your 'Starting' and 'Ending' strings, like `[]`

For `$str = ' blah blah [Starting String] something [Ending String] blah blah';` the result would be `blah blah  blah blah`

Comment: How can i replace by condition. Ex. if text is a then replace by b, if text is c then replace by d.

Comment: @dungphanxuan use `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use preg_replace.  I haven't tested it, but something along the lines of:

```
$str = "Starting String foo bar Ending String"
$pattern = '/^Starting String(.+)Ending String$/'
$replacement = ''
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

You will have to make sure that Starting String and Ending String do not contain any special regex characters or that they are properly escaped.

Comment: I think Cheery's answer is probably a little more correct than mine

Answer (score 1):

```
define('STARTING', 'starting string');

$ending = 'ending string';
$string = 'starting stringSomething Hereending string';

function get_anything($string, $ending, &$anything)
{
    if (strpos($string, STARTING) !== 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (substr($string, strlen($ending) * -1) != $ending)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $anything = substr($string, strlen(STARTING));
    $anything = substr_replace($anything, '', strlen($ending) * -1, -1);
    return true;
}

if (get_anything($string, $ending, $anything))
{
    echo $anything;
}
```

The function `get_anything` will return `false` if the pattern is not found, and `true` if it is found. The "anything" in the middle will be returned in the third parameter.